# Java Swing "pack" - GTK Equivalent

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have for example this code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("foo.bar", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How can I automatically resize the window, so it has the perfect size for the one button.

With Java Swing, you could simply call [`pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#pack()), but I wasn't able to find a similar method for GTK.

For GtkWindow there would be `gtk_window_resize`, but it requires giving an height and width, so I would have to calculate it manually.
This would work with just one button, but anything more complex would be error-prone and prone to failure.

Is there any equivalent to `pack`?

Comment: You should start by not setting the default size.